# Is it possible to use Ajax to POST data from within a Server-Side Javascript in the Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ajax, ssjs, post

Is it possible to use Ajax to POST data from within a Server-Side Javascript in the Marketing Cloud?
Could the FormData be a problem?

I've been using this code:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("email", "test@test.com");
form.append("first name", "test");
form.append("last name", "test");
form.append("lists", "47");


var url = 'http://existing.working.website.com/';
var contentType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
var payload = form;
var headerNames = ["cache-control", "postman-token"];
var headerValues = ["no-cache", "a5f59d70-84dc-dce6-8809-03aa098cad3d"];
//var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);
var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);

Write("result: "+result.StatusCode + '<br>');
Write(result.Response);
```

and this one:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("email", "test@test.com");
form.append("first name", "test");
form.append("last name", "test");
form.append("lists", "47");


var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://existing.working.website.com/",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "a5f59d70-84dc-dce6-8809-03aa098cad3d"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should *technically* be possible, and I can't see anything off the top of my head that would cause a problem with your code, but I think it's useful to remind people who may read this that SSJS runs on page load and then anything else responsive or reactive would need to be client-side javascript. Same goes for ampscript.

Generally when you're using ajax you're working with the user post-page load to perform actions while they interact with the page, so you lose all the benefits of Ajax with SSJS as it can never engage with the user.